# Finding intermediate fields and zeroes of a splitting field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $g(X) = X^3 + X^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ and $K = \mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$. Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$ of degree 4. Let $\beta$ be a root of $f$ and let $L$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

**Question 1:** how many intermediate fields does $L/K$ have?

**Question 2:** why are all zeroes of $f$ of the form $\beta^k$ for some integer $k$?

My proffessor says those questions are closely related, so I ask them both in the same post.

I've already made some progress: as $g(0) = g(1) = 1 \neq 0$, $g$ is irreducible, so $K \cong \mathbb{F}_2/(g)$. Because every $x \in K$ can be written as $a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2$ with  $a, b, c \in \mathbb{F}_2$, we have that $K$ has characteristic 2. The amount of intermediates fields is equal to the the amount of proper subgroups of $Gal(L/K)$. As $f$ is of degree 4 and irreducible, we have that $|Gal(L/K)| = 4$. So $Gal(L/K)$ is either isomorphic to the cyclic group (1 proper subgroup, namely $<2>$) or to the Klein-Gruppe (3 proper subgroups, namely $<(1, 0)>, <(0, 1)>, <(1, 1)>$). How do we find out which group it is isomorphic to?

For the second question I have zero clue how to solve it. I put in $\beta^k$ in $f$, but that doesn't simplify to anything nice, even knowing that $K$ has characteristic 2.

Comment: "The amount of intermediates fields is equal to the order of $Gal(L/K)$" NO!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I meant proper (my text doesn't consider $L$ and $K$ intermediate fields) subgroups, thank you.

Comment: All the elements of $K$ satisfy the equation $x^8=x$. This applies to the coefficients of $f$ in particular. So, can you show that if $f(\beta)=0$ then also $f(\beta^8)=0$. Mind you, using this you can show that $K[x]/(f)$ is a splitting field, isomorphic to $L$, and only after this can you conclude that $Gal(L/K)$ is of order four.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen wouldn't $x^8 = 1$? As $K$ is a group under multiplication (because $K$ is a field), and $|K| = 8$, it follows by Lagrange that the order of $x$ divides 8, so $x^8$ is the identity 1 if I'm thinking correctly.

Comment: Only $K^*=K\setminus\{0_K\}$ is a group under multiplication. It has seven elements, so $x^7=1$ for all non-zero $x\in K$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen would this be correct? $f(\beta^8) = a_4\beta^{32} + a_3\beta^{24} + a_2\beta^{16} + a_1\beta^8 + a_0 = (a_4\beta^4)^{8} + (a_3\beta^3)^8 + (a_2\beta^{2})^8 + (a_1\beta)^8 + a_0^8 = f(\beta) = 0$ because the characteristic of the field is 2 ($(a_1 + ... + a_n)^2 = (a_1 + ... + a_n)$ which we can apply 3 times). So in general $\beta^{8k}$ is a zero for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But how would we prove that these are all zeroes?

Comment: Not quite, $\beta^{8^k}$ is a zero for all $k$. There are only finitely many zeros (how many?), these will start repeating after some point. Given that $f$ is irreducible when would that happen?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen there are 4 zeroes. There cannot be more than 4 different $\beta^{8^k}$ because $|L\backslash\{0\}| = 4095$, but it's possible that the order of $\beta$ is 3 in which case $\beta = \beta^{64}$, so in that case we have no more than 3 zeroes of the form $\beta^{8^k}$. Or is that not possible?